# Find record with multiple search criteria including between range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a record using multiple search criteria. I want to match an employee's role and the number of years between min year and max year to the "Title" below. I want to stick to using functions if possible.

```
Title           Role     Min Year   Max Year
Senior Sales    Sales       6      99
Middle Sales    Sales       2      5
Junior Sales    Sales       0      1
Sr. Counsel     Counsel     0      99
Jr Counsel      Counsel     0      99
Senior Staff    Staff       6      99
Middle Staff    Staff       2      5
Junior Staff    Staff       0      1
Other           Other       0     99
```

For Example, Bill is in sales for one year and should have the Title Junior Sales. Joe, staff for 10 years, should be Senior Staff.

```
ID  Last    Name    Title   Seniority   Expected Result
1   Nye     Bill    Sales   1           Junior Sales 
2   Smith   Joe     Staff   10          Senior Staff
```

This formula returns the right result, but only when it's the "Senior" level title, not the others (#REF).

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH($D20,$B$2:$B$10,0),MATCH($E20,$D$2:$D$10,-1))
```

Here's a formula that returns the first instance of the Role:

```
=INDEX(A2:A10,AND(MATCH(D20,B2:B10,0),SUMPRODUCT(--(E20<=D2:D10),--(E20>=C2:C10))))
```

It returns "Senior Sales" instead of "Junior Sales".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a non CSE array formula:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MAX(INDEX(($B$2:$B$10=J2)*($C$2:$C$10<=K2)*($D$2:$D$10>=K2)*(ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$2)+1),)))
```

[image]

Comment: One thing to watch is if none of the data matches the max function still returns a 0.  Index can do weird things if you have the row number=0.  Apparently it returns the value in the same row as the formula is entered or a 0 if the formula is in a row outside the index row range.

Comment: @gtwebb you are correct.  If there is no match it will return the first row every time.

Comment: I was playing with it a bit and it doesn't always return the first row.  As stated above it seems to depend on which row the formula is entered on.

Comment: @gtwebb fascinating, personally I would have gone with yours, hence the up vote.  I just wanted to give an non CSE formula.

Answer (score 1):

Using an array formula (enter with **ctrl+shift+enter**) you could use this

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(1,(E20>$C$2:$C$10)*(E20<=$D$2:$D$10)*($B$2:$B$10=D20),0))
```

comparision statements return an array of 0s (false) and 1s (true).  When all three are true they multiply together to return a 1 which is then matched within the match function.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you keep your lookup table arranged like that, this code works for me:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH($D20,$B$2:$B$10,0) + MATCH($E20,$D$2:$D$10,-1) - 1 )
```